# Ceilometer launch error with ceilometer-collector

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-swift

I am trying to install Ceilometer for collecting Swift usage data and having a bunch of problems. I am following the link below to install and run Ceilometer for Swift:

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/ceilometer/install/manual.html#installing-manually

I am stuck at step 9 i.e. when I try to launch *ceilometer-collector*, I get the following error:

```
 **# ceilometer-collector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ceilometer-collector", line 6, in <module>
    from ceilometer.collector.service import collector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ceilometer/collector/service.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ceilometer.service import prepare_service
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ceilometer/service.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ceilometer.openstack.common import gettextutils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ceilometer/openstack/common/gettextutils.py", line 34, in <module>
    from babel import localedata
ImportError: No module named babel**
```

I have following some questions:

1) What does the option set in step 8.1 in the link above? I mean in `/etc/ceilometer/ceilometer.conf`, there're no Swift options for `*_control_exchange`
2) Has anyone successfully installed Ceilometer for Swift? Any step-by-step guide would be immensely helpful as the link above is generic for manual installation.

My configuration is the following:

Management server running the collector, data store, central agent, 2 proxy servers and 3 storage nodes. Everything is running on OpenStack Grizzly on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

The place for more information would be developer documentation http://docs.openstack.org/developer/ceilometer/measurements.html#object-storage-swift

Also check the official project page https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Ceilometer

Feel free to join the developer mailing list and posting the feature request if you think more matrix needed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

here is a post with trouble shooting for Ceilometer Havana on SLES 11 SP3, http://zqfan.github.io/openstack/2014/03/18/enable-swift-meter-on-suse/

the message "ImportError: No module named babel" means you have not installed the depended python lib.

Swift sample is sent by a ceilometer middleware, which is happen in API request, so I think there is no such swift_control_exchage option